# google extension find words of variable in current tab source code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building my first google extension, want to know how to make a function that searches a specified word in web page source code

I've already found this code that highlights the numbers in page but i cannot get it to work

```
var numberArray = [155];

numberArray.forEach(function(v){

  var num = "(" + v + ")";
  var td = $('td.col-question:contains('+num+')');

  if(td.length > 0){

    var span = td.html().replace(num,'<span class="highlight-num">'+num+'</span>');
    var n = td.html(span);

  }

});
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? Are you trying to highlight a number in a table?  Or trying to find a word in a web page?

Comment: finding a word in web page then highlight it